# Replace values in Rust vector that satify condition

Tags: rust

What would be the most idiomatic Rust way of replacing any element in a vector that equals some value - **inplace**?

The solution I currently have is

```rust
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 2];
v.iter_mut().for_each(|x| if *x == 2 {*x = 0} else {});

assert_eq!(vec![1, 0, 3, 3, 6, 0], v)
```

in this example I replace all values of 2 with 0. The reason this irks me is that the `else` arm is empty...which makes me think I'm missing something "cleaner"?

Comment: we can skip `else` part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `else`?

```rust
v.iter_mut().for_each(|x| {
    if *x == 2 {
        *x = 0
    }
});
```

Additionally, I would replace `for_each` with a `for` loop, as it is considered more idiomatic (see [`for_each()`'s docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each)):

```rust
for x in &mut v {
    if *x == 2 {
        *x = 0
    }
}
```

If you like iterator chains, you can do:

```rust
v.iter_mut().filter(|x| **x == 2).for_each(|x| *x = 0);
```

But I think the `for` loop is clearer.